# Apache Zookeeper Server Fail

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am getting the following error message
ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@66] - Unexpected execption, exiting abnormally.  I tried to find on google but unable to locate anything with main@66.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got control over ZK, you should debug it. It is pretty easy, just append something like

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

to JVMFLAG at zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh and restart it.